# Oracle SQL Subtract columns with case condition in Apex IG

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

In my oracle apex interactive grid source query, i have 2 columns.

Both are by default float in DB but need to be represented as comma separated, hence the usage of to_char.

The first column is simple and second is derived via case.

Now i need to subtract these 2 and put result in a 3rd virtual column.

When i write the query something like:

```
 select to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999.99') CURRENT_KPI, 
case when dept=1 then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999.99') 
else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999.99') end as NEW_KPI, 
CURRENT_KPI-NEW_KPI RESULT 
from KPI_DATA;
```

So here i get error, NEW_KPI is invalid identifier, whether i validate in application or run in oracle database(sql developer 19)

How can i write the query to subtract CURRENT_KPI and the result of NEW_KPI

Oracle 12c
Apex 20.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat your transformation:

```
select 
  to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999.99') CURRENT_KPI, 
  case 
    when dept=1 then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999.99') 
    else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999.99') 
  end as NEW_KPI, 
  KPI_1 - 
  case
    when dept=1 then KPI_2
    else KPI_3
  end as RESULT 
from KPI_DATA;
```

In a fast way, you could do it like this:

```
select 
  to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999.99') CURRENT_KPI || ';' || 
  case 
    when dept=1 then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999.99') 
    else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999.99') 
  end as NEW_KPI || ';' ||
  to_char(
    KPI_1 -
    case 
      when dept=1 then KPI_2
      else KPI_3
    end,
    '999,999,999,999.99'
    )
from KPI_DATA;
```

Comment: This would work, but there's one more issue. The result is also required in comma separated format. So how do i get that. Because this query that you shared gives invalid number. If i write this: select 
  to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999.99') CURRENT_KPI, 
  case 
    when dept=1 then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999.99') 
    else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999.99') 
  end as NEW_KPI, 
  CURRENT_KPI - 
  case 
    when dept=1 then KPI_2
    else KPI_3
  end as RESULT 
from KPI_DATA; --Here result column gives number in float format. How do i convert result also as comma separated?

Comment: try with second query

Comment: Your second query appears to be using a mix of T-SQL (declaring the variable and using the `+` operator for string concatenation) and Oracle SQL (using the `to_char` function).

Comment: Yes you are right, i mixed both systems. I have modified it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to replicate the `case` statement.  And you want to subtract numbers not strings

```
select to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999.99') CURRENT_KPI, 
       case when dept=1 
            then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999.99') 
            else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999.99') 
        end as NEW_KPI, 
       to_char( kpi_1 - case when dept=1 
                             then kpi_2
                             else kpi_3
                          end,
                 '999,999,999,999.99' ) result
from KPI_DATA;
```

As a rule, though, I would strongly suggest that your query returns a number and you deal with formatting the number in the column properties of your interactive grid.  That way you're letting the display component handle how to display data and the data component handle what data to fetch.